# How to remove the empty space that is created with ggpubr stat_pvalue_manual hide.ns = true?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr, rstatix

When the `stat_pvalue_manual` function of ggpubr is called:

```
ggplot + stat_pvalue_manual(statistics, label = "p.adj.signif", 
                 coord.flip = TRUE,
                 #hide.ns = TRUE, 
                 tip.length = 0,
                 bracket.size = 0)+coord_flip()
```

The following graph is produced:
[image: stat_pvalue_manual with ns]

However, I am only interested in data that is significant, therefore I have omitted non-significant data by calling `hide.ns = TRUE` as follows:

```
ggplot + stat_pvalue_manual(statistics, label = "p.adj.signif", 
                 coord.flip = TRUE,
                 hide.ns = TRUE, 
                 tip.length = 0,
                 bracket.size = 0)+coord_flip()
```

This creates empty space that the non-significant data previously occupied. Is there a way to remove it?

[image: stat_pvalue_manual without ns]

To calculate the xy positions, this is done as follows in the statistics object:

```
statistics <- dataframe %>%
tukey_hsd(value~group) %>%
add_xy_position(fun = "mean_se", x= "group")
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will `ggbreak` help there? To create a break between ~ 8 and 13? https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggbreak/vignettes/ggbreak.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by filtering the statistics table to only show significant values.

```r
statistics <- statistics %>% filter(p.adj.signif != "ns")

ggplot + stat.pvalue_manual(statistics, label = "p.adj.signif")
```